# Difference between Message and Signal in Communication Theory

Tags: theory, signal-theory

What is the difference between a **message** and a **signal** in Communication Theory?
It seems to me that often they coincide, is this always?

Comment: I don't think "message" is a formal term of communication theory, unless you have a definition of it. But in that case you should know the difference. But intuitively - message is a package of *information*. Signal is something that can be used to transmit messages, but not necessarily. Same message can be transmitted using different kinds of signals.

Comment: @EugeneSh. -> answer?

Comment: A signal can carry many messages. It is also possible to transmit a message on multiple signals. So...

Comment: They are poorly defined words. Always look to see how the author of any given work is using them. The time when you insist that either can mean only one particular thing, and that everybody is using them that way, is the time when you drop exam marks for not spotting that the question was using them differently.

Answer (score 2):

A signal is simply a quantity varying over time (or some other axis); a message is something that you *could* form a signal from. (e.g. the message "I have tooth pain" could be made into an acoustic signal coming out of your mouth, or as UTF-32 bits that are then source-, channel-coded, encrypted, interleaved, mapped to a 1024-QAM, pulse shaped, modulated onto a 6 GHz carrier to come out as varying electric field strength in front of a horn antenna)

But, honestly, these are *words*; as **anything**, their meaning depends on context. So, you need to look for that context.

Hence,

> is this always

**never** applies to anything aside from things with a very fundamental canonical definition (e.g., a "prime number" is always the same thing, not depending on context; what "cheese" is, or a "thought", or "meaning", or "message": not so much).

Answer (score 1):

Signalling communicates one element.

Messages consist of a number of elements.

They don't coincide. A really simplified analogy is: if it was language, then a signal is a single letter and a message is the actual words.

The signalling method can vary from one implementation to another and still carry the same messages. For instance, a UART can use LVTTL levels, TTL levels or RS232C levels to connect to another UART and the data bytes (messages) communicated will be the same.

Comment: Or a signal is a continuous radio broadcast, which can carry a sequence of messages.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Figure 1 from Claude Shannon's "A Mathematical Theory of Communication", which is widely considered the foundational paper in the field of Information Theory:

[image]

([source](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf))

As defined here, a message is the information to be transmitted. The signal is the form in which it is transmitted it over the communication channel.

The basic definition of the message is implied in the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of the paper:

> The significant aspect is that the actual message is one selected from a set of possible messages. The system must be designed to operate for each possible selection, not just the one which will actually be chosen since this is unknown at the time of design.
>
> If the number of messages in the set is finite then this number or any monotonic function of this number can be regarded as a measure of the information produced when one message is chosen from the set, all choices being equally likely

Comment: This is definitely the most canonical source for a definition! Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

**Signal** refers to the waveform itself.

You can have a carrier signal, baseband signal etc. Signals have a shape and characteristics that can be mathematically defined.

---

The idea is that a signal may carry **information**, which is anything not known apriori to the receiver; i.e., a receiver cannot recreate it on its own. e.g., a receiver may locally generate the carrier signal at the standard frequency but it has no new information in each cycle and repeats endlessly.

A signal could be carrying information belonging to one user only. e.g. beating of drums or a telegraph signal. In modern times, a signal transmits information for many users in a multiplexed fashion as channel bandwidth is expensive.

---

**Message** is information belonging to a single entity and intended for one or many users. It may arrive using a signal, or many signals. On networks, a message is digitized and packetized to use channel capacity efficiently and arrives at the destination through multiple routers.

Further you can think of a message as a properly formatted sequence of information that follows a protocol and can be received by using standard equipment at the other end.

---

A signal (waveform) may or may not carry information.

An information bearing signal may not carry a (complete) message or indeed any useful message.

A message contains useful information intended for one or many entities.